# using slick.js for a flickr feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm working on implementing a flickr feed to a page inside of a slick.js slider.

I've been able to load the images into the slider, but the images has varied widths and are displaying a little wonky. each div being created adopts the same width, even if the image inside it is thinner.

See page here: http://abenjamin765.github.io/pushpinevents

html

```
<div class="slider" style="width:500px; background:#666;">

</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        arrows: true
        });


  $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157647565496672&nsid=127682596@N07&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
      var squares = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_q.jpg');
      var large = (item.media.m).replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');

      if(i <= 20){
        $('.slider').slickAdd('<div class="slide-img"><a href="' + large + '"><img src="' + large + '"/></a></div>');
      }
    });
  });



});
```

Comment: why not loading with [Masonry Js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) that way, even if picture are wider or taller than others, it will all fit perfectly... no?

Comment: i dont think Masonry offers a carousel.

Comment: no, but it's easy to implement auto-load scrolling for example...